# dynamically update options_for_select

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to populate the second select option based on what is selected on the first select option. I know how to do it with traditional jquery and html. But wanted to know if there is anyway I can just update *options_for_select*.

As you can see I have a helper function *city_for_select* in the first option. I want to use the same kind of approach for the second one also. I will appreciate any help. Than you.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <%= f.label t('city'), class: "form-control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.select :city, options_for_select(city_for_select), {}, class: "form-control", id: "city" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <%= f.label t('area'), class: "form-control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.select :area, options_for_select(["Plz select"]), {}, class: "form-control", id: "area" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another approach of doing things. After adding the controller function and relevant routing I use jquery and json to call the function and load in the select options. No need to render partials here.

Controller: *Please note that you have to return data in json format*.

```
def area_for_city
  city = params[:city]
  if city == "city1"
    @areas = ["area1", "area2"]
  elsif city == "city2"
    @areas = ["area3", "area4"]
  elsif city == "city3"
    @areas == ["area5", "area6"]
  end

  render json: {areas: @areas}
end
```

Javascript:

```
function populate_area(city_name){
  $.get("/get_area_for_city", {city: city_name}, function(data){
    var $area = $('#area');
    $area.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.areas.length; i++) {
      $area.append('<option value=' + data.areas[i] + '>' + data.areas[i] + '</option>');
    }
  }, "json");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#city").change(function () {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val == "city1") {
          populate_area("city1");
      } else if (val == "city2") {
          populate_area("city2");
      } else if (val == "city3") {
          populate_area("city3");
      }
  });
});
```

HTML is already given in the question.

Comment: This is a better approach than mine because you can easily swap out the view layer, or move to js framework easier without touching the returning partials and such. Well done!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your input :)

Comment: Very clean and easy solution, I like this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to extract the second `options_for_select` into a controller method. Then use some JS to call said method when the first select changes. Use jQuery to replace/set HTML for the second `options_for_select`.

So like you said. Same principle as traditional HTML/jQuery but the HTML will come from rails controller

Controller:

```
def update_select
  # Your query here
  # Populate @t
end
```

View (update_select.js.erb):

```
$("#sencond_select").html("<%= j render partial: 'update_select' %>");
```

Partial (_update_select.html.erb):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= label_tag t('area'), nil, class: "form-control-label" %><br>
  <%= select_tag :area, options_for_select(["Plz select"]), class: "form-control", id: "area" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ruslan, Thank you for the answer. But that is where I am stuck. Do you know what is the exact code to update the options_for_select with jquery? I tried something like? `$("#area").options_for_select(helper_function)`, doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I was actually trying or looking for something different. See my answer.  Its the same approach in the sense that I am calling a controller function. But loading data part is a bit different. Let me know what do you think?